# How to add Cache headers to Cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using cloudfront with no special settings.  when I run webpagetest, it gives me an "F" for static content.  Is there any way to get cloudfront to put out the correct cache headers?

Here are my results from a page that has cloudfront.  I'm not sure this is still live

http://www.webpagetest.org/result/150207_29_PAF/1/details/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add these headers (max-age or expires) on your origin. It is the origin that decides how long objects should stay in cache

Comment: or [Cache-Control](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/), which is typically even better.

Comment: Yep, agree. I just quoted error message from the test result mentioned